# How to disable all consumers and producers in spring cloud streams application:

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way we can disable all consumer and producer beans from initializing when configuration is absent in spring cloud stream.

We started migrating our app to use spring cloud streams and we want to push the code but configuration will be present some time in the future. Spring cloud stream is initializing all beans listing on localhost when we dont provide any configuration.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Can you explain the following:
1. What do you mean by consumer and producer beans?
2. What configuration is missing and how it may come in the future?
3. Give that your app "may not be functioning when deployed", what are you trying to accomplish by deploying a non-functioning app?
4. What do you mean by ". . .initializing all beans listing on localhost"? Are you talking about default connections?
5. Which binder are you using? Rabbit? Kafka?

Comment: Hi Oleg .. sorry for not been clear. 1) I meant to say the bindings. 2) We would like to deploy 2 instances of this app .. 1 should work with out these bindings and one should one work with the bindings using the configuration specified. 4) When we don't specify the any binding configuration in the app yml .. these bindings are starting with default host pointing to localhost. 5) We are using kafka for now.  We would like to have a mechanism to disable these bindings when configuration is not present.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. If I am reading this correctly you want to deploy the app which is not bound to anything? What value are you trying to get out of it? I guess this is more of an architectural question and framework may or may not support the architecture you envision. So for now, I guess I want to get more clarity on #3

Comment: @Oleg .. the specific micro service have some other functionality which need to be working after the deployment. I want to push my code related to spring cloud streams with out any configuration or disabling it until the other team starts pushing messages to this specific kafka topic. I could keep these changes in a feature branch until its ready .. but I am looking to see if there is a option to disable these binders. Let me know if its still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do not bind any broker service for the configurations?

The application can have the consumer and producer beans but cannot be used.

Note: This might cause the actuator health endpoint to show app as down.